# Setting a form_validation custom message like in callback

Tags: codeigniter, validation, message

Normally, I can use this , in the callback function:

```
$this->form_validation->set_message("_custom", "My custom message.");
```

But this will work *only* inside of the callback function which before was set like this:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('something', 'Something', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_custom');
```

My question is - How can I use `$this->form_validation->set_message` to work on a field name like its working on the callback function?

So I could use something like this: `$this->form_validation->set_message('field_name', 'custom message');` without any callbacks.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a nice way to do this: https://bitbucket.org/kuroir/codeigniter/changeset/fd8986fdc408

Answer (score 3):

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('myfield', 'My Field Name', 'trim|required|callback_name_function');  


public function name_function()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('name_function', 'Hello World !');
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Returning false marks the validation as failed. You can add custom validators by using "callback_" followed by the name of the public method. The set_message function must use the name of the function - this keeps it generic so the validation logic can be used for any number of fields.